# Can an angular directive require its own controller?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is a simple question but I can't seem to find any relevant documentation...

I'm trying to find out if an angular directive can both inherit a parent controller *as well as its own*.  Consider the following examples:

**Simple Inheritance From Self**

```
app.directive('screen', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: function() {
        this.doSomething = function() {

        };
    },
    link: function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
        // ctrl now contains `doSomething`
    }
  }
});
```

**Inheritance From Parent**

```
app.directive('screen', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: function() {
        this.doSomething = function() {

        };
    }
  }
});
app.directive('widget', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    require: '^screen',
    link: function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
        // ctrl now contains `doSomething` -- inherited from the `screen` directive
    }
  }
});
```

**There's even multiple inheritance...**

```
app.directive('screen', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: function() {
        this.doSomething = function() {

        };
    }
  }
});
app.directive('widget', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    require: ['^screen','^anotherParent'],
    link: function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
        // ctrl[0] now contains `doSomething` -- inherited from the `screen` directive
        // ctrl[1] now contains the controller inherited from `anotherParent`
    }
  }
});
```

What I can't figure out is how to make a directive inherit both a parent controller and its own.  Like so:

```
app.directive('screen', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: function() {
        this.doSomething = function() {

        };
    }
  }
});
app.directive('widget', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    require: '^screen',
    controller: function($scope) {
       // isolated widget controller
    },
    link: function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
        // I need the `screen` controller in ADDITION to the isolated widget controller accessible in the link
    }
  }
});
```

Is this possible/proper form (or is it some kind of anti-pattern I am unaware of)?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

Well that turned out to be a lot more obvious than I thought... a little trial and error showed that a directive can actually require itself as well.

**The proper way to inherit parent + local controllers seems to be:**

```
app.directive('screen', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    controller: function() {
        this.doSomething = function() {

        };
    }
  }
});
app.directive('widget', function() {
  return {
    scope: true,
    require: ['^screen','widget'],
    controller: function($scope) {
       this.widgetDoSomething = function() {
       };
    },
    link: function($scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
        // ctrl[0] contains the `screen` controller
        // ctrl[1] contains the local `widget` controller
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: that's the way i'm doing it now... my SO search was hoping to reveal a more 'elegant' method. I guess this is just how it's done =/

Comment: I'm so glad you asked this question, I was having a heck of a time figuring it out.

Comment: Why do you need ^ to require the screen directive?